# How to make partitions for the Single Image into multiple views for clickable to change ON/OFF buttons

Tags: javascript, image, react-native

[[image: Image that shows ON/OFF buttons]]

I am working on a sample app in react-native. In that i had a Single Image that contains "ON" and "OFF" buttons. when i click "ON" button it has to change "OFF" and vice-versa. For that i have to do partition for the each button to be clickable on a particular portion/partition in that image.

Comment: I would probably create an ONOFFButton Component which will be positioned above the image with `position: 'absolute'` and change between ON and OFF when tapped.

Comment: Hi @MilanGulyas thanks for your valuable reply. I used your method position: 'absolute' is working fine but, when I use touchableopacity for ON/OFF button Images the buttons or not overlaying on the background Image.Please, suggest me to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you share some code please? Either edit the post or link a repository. Would help a lot.

Comment: Hi @MilanGulyas i gave position:'absolute' style to <TouchableOpacity> tag, In that I placed <Image> tag. Now it is working fine. I got best answer from you.Thanks for your help.